# WPF format igdp value

Tags: wpf, format, infragistics

I have salary list. To list salary data I, use infragistics datapresenter igdp.
But I have problem. in this list ,If person is company employe , I have to mask the amount as hidden like ***** .if person is not employe ,no need to hide amount. I try to use converter but ıt isnt work. can you help me ?

```
  <igDP:Field Name="Amount" Label="Amount">
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowSummaries="True" EditorType="{x:Type BNumericEditor}"   >
                            <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type BNumericEditor}">
                                    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="{}{double:10.2}"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                        </igDP:FieldSettings>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
```

I try to use convert in wpf but it isn work for me

Comment: Bind directly to a `FormattedAmount` property or use a `CellValuePresenterStyle` to change the appearance of the cell?